# Does Fit.Line use least squares

Tags: c#, math.net

The method [Fit.Line](http://Curve%20Fitting:%20Linear%20Regression) - what algorithm does it use to determine the parameters? Hopefully least squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation.
https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/Fit.htm#Line

"Least-Squares fitting the points (x,y) to a line y : x -> a+b*x, returning its best fitting parameters as [a, b] array, where a is the intercept and b the slope."